# Magento 2: Left Category Sidebar from Sebwite

Tags: categories, sidebar, magento2

I'm using Magento 2 and still struggle implementing this category listing url: 
https://github.com/Sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar

What is the proper way to do this line below? Which file should i edit?

> You should implement the block Sebwite\Sidebar\Block\Sidebar in your theme to make this extension work.

As i am new to this, i cannot find any instruction regarding this knowing i should have missed something here.

I have try several attempts but it seems the left category still not showing.

I have tried to edit `/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml` but still no luck.

Below is my default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <container name="compare-link-wrapper" label="Compare Link Wrapper" as="compare-link-wrapper" after="top.search" htmlTag="ul" htmlClass="compare wrapper">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="catalog.compare.link" before="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/compare/link.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="compareProducts" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/view/compare-products</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
        <block class="Sebwite\Sidebar\Block\Sidebar" name="category-sidebar" template="Sebwite_Sidebar::sidebar.phtml" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Any suggestions is very appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this works for me.

Go to your magento luma catalog-layout *default.xml* and change it to below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <container name="compare-link-wrapper" label="Compare Link Wrapper" as="compare-link-wrapper" after="top.search" htmlTag="ul" htmlClass="compare wrapper">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="catalog.compare.link" before="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/compare/link.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="compareProducts" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/view/compare-products</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Sebwite\Sidebar\Block\Sidebar" name="category-sidebar" template="Sebwite_Sidebar::sidebar.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I use this extension and found that it is also showing up the "Default Category" in sidebar , the same extension is working fine in local server using the same configuration. Any idea what could be the reason for this issue ?